# Topology - Open set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How do I show this?

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $x\in X$ an element in $X$. Show that
\begin{align*}
\{y\in X|d(y,x)>r\}
\end{align*}
is open for any $r\in \mathbb{R}$.

The definition of a open set in my book:
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A subset $U\subseteq X$ is **open** when the following conditions are met:
\begin{align*}
\forall x_0\in U\,\exists r>0:\,B_r(x_0)\subseteq U
\end{align*}

Comment: Write the set as a union of open sets or show that the complement is closed.

Comment: One possibility is using the following definition:

$U$ is *open* $\iff$ every $x \in U$ is an *inner point*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y\in X$ such that $d(y,x)>r$, and choose $\epsilon$ such that $0 < \epsilon < d(x,y) - r$.  We claim that $$B(y,\epsilon):= \{z\in X|d(y,z)<\epsilon\} \subseteq \{y\in X|d(y,x)>r\},$$ so the open ball $B(y,\epsilon)$ is contained in any arbitrary point $y$ in the given subset of $X$.

Let $z \in B(y,\epsilon)$, then $d(y,z)<\epsilon < d(x,y) - r$.  By the Triangle inequality, $$d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y).$$  Rearranging gives $$d(x,z) \ge d(x,y) - d(z,y) > d(x,y) - (d(x,y) - r) = r.$$

Hence, $\{y\in X|d(y,x)>r\}$ is open in $X$.

[image: a picture illustrating the proof]
[$\rm \LaTeX$ Source code](https://gist.github.com/VincentTam/96b4aebd1dd26bb95164)

Comment: The picture says it all - well done. Such a picture is actually a proof if we only allow certain "basic steps" in its construction, each step being a consequence of an axiom in the definition of a metric space. But I don't know if this has been spelled out somewhere before.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Though I draw the picture myself using TikZ, the idea is universal.  I think similar pictures can be found in the Internet.

Comment: I understand this answer a little better than the other. Especially the picture is very useful for my understanding, thank you.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Can you elaborate how the last inequality gives that $\{y\in X|d(y,x)>r\}$ is open?

Comment: @dk20 The last inequality shows that $z \in B(y,\epsilon) \implies z \in \{y\in X|d(y,x)>r\}$, so the first central-aligned "equation" holds: $$B(y,\epsilon) \subseteq \{y\in X|d(y,x)>r\}.$$ Thus, for any point $y$ in the given subset, there exists an open ball $B(y,\epsilon)$ contained in the given subset.  This is the (usually taught) definition of open sets in metric spaces.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Thanks that helped for my understanding! Yes that definition is also the one in my book.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I'm actually still a little unsure about this part: $> d(x,y) - (d(x,y) - r) > r$ Isn't it the same as: $r>r$?

Comment: @dk20 Sorry,  That's a typo.  I'll correct this now.  Thanks for spotting that out.

Answer (score 5):

The triangle inequality implies that

$|d(y,x) - d(y',x)| \leq d(y,y').$

It follows that $d(-,x) : X \to \mathbb{R} $ is continuous (in fact, [Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity)). Hence, the preimage under the open subset $]r,\infty[ \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open, and this is your set.

Comment: Neat and beautiful argument!

Comment: I just started on topology so I'm not the best at it, but I think I get it, so thank you.